# Exception: Can't start async operation (refresh inventory) because another async operation(launchPurchaseFlow) is in progress

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Yes, there are two common answers to this problem:

One: A hack where one calls `billingHelper.flagEndAsync();` before starting an async operation. This is generally considered as not recommended, and doesn't solve the problem in many cases.

Two: Calling the IabHelper's `handleActivityResult`method in the Activity's `onActivityResult`. The problem with this solution (besides me not understanding the purpose of this method) is that in my app the in-app billing operations are done in the app's Application class, because there are a bunch of activities in the application where a user may trigger an in-app purchase, and multiple possible entry points where there app needs to query the in-app purchase inventory. So I tried putting:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!MyApplication.myAppInstance.mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))    
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

into every activity where a user might start a purchase, but this has not solved the crashes. I don't really understand the purpose of this onActivityResult stuff, so I probably misunderstood how it's supposed to be implemented. Why does Google want to force me to do in-app billing operations from an activity anyway?

Comment: "Why does Google want to force me to do in-app billing operations from an activity anyway?" - Where else would you perform in-app billing operations from?

Comment: From the application class so the code can be used by any activity.

Comment: If you hold a reference to the IabHelper in your `Application` class and never dispose of it properly, this will cause a memory leak (the connection with the Google Play process will persist forever and those resources will never be released). I'm pretty sure the `IabHelper` class was meant to be used on a per-Activity basis (i.e. in each `Activity` create/setup an instance in `onCreate` and dispose of it in `onDestroy`.

Comment: Also, it is important to understand the purpose of `onActivityResult` in this case. When you call `launchPurchaseFlow`, your application sends a message to the Google Play process to launch the familiar "purchase" Activity dialog. At this point, the user will either cancel or buy your item (or an error will occur) and the activity dialog will be dismissed. When the activity is dismissed, your `onActivityResult` method will be called, and the `IabHelper` will need to analyze the `requestCode` and `resultCode` in order to determine whether or not the user successfully purchased the item.

Comment: Well that sucks. Thanks for the explanation. I guess that means I can just create/destroy an iabHelper instance in every activity and pass it to the method that does in-app billing operations in my Application class? What complicates matters is that this error happens to a small number of users relative to the in-app purchases made and never happens to me, so I can't be sure if it fixes the issue until crash reports stop coming in.

Comment: You must write an billing wrapper by your own to prevent code repetition on every billing page inside your app. This wrapper would handle the IabHelper initialization and release once an item has been purchased

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Unfortunately the `IabHelper` code is not great... it's mostly good, but the threading model is kind of messy, which means it can become confusing how to properly handle the edge cases.

An easy way to get rid of the crashes is to simply wrap the method call with an if-statement check like:

```
if (!mHelper.isAsyncInProgress()) {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(...);
}
```

A better solution would be to rewrite the `IabHelper` code from scratch... but in this particular case the exception happens so rarely that it's probably not worth it. Unfortunately there isn't an easy fix in this case... the `IabHelper` sample code isn't the greatest and most of us will just decide to live with it.

Comment: isAsyncInProgress does not exists on IAB V3

Comment: Yeah, I know. I had to create the method myself.

Comment: @FireZenk Alex left out his implementation, but since IabHelper has a member variable for this, all you need to do is edit IabHelper.java and add:

    public boolean isAsyncInProgress()
    {
     return mAsyncInProgress;
    }

Answer (score 4):

Having a flag to launchPurchaseFlow ignores multiple launches of purchase flow. But unfortunately, this fails if user clicks on Back Button by mistake from Google In App Billing serviceIntent. Flag should be reset to false in this case. Otherwise, user will not be able to try to purchase again.

```
if(!mHelper.isAsyncInProgress())
{
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(...);
}

// Invoke below method to reset onBackPressed
public static void resetAsyncInProgress() {
    mHelper.setAsyncInProgress(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks of the info about "back" button causing the issue.